# xarray gives HDF error when iterating through opendap datasets

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am trying to download some data from an OpenDAP server using xarray and python 3.7 on Windows 10, iterating through a series of stations and years and writing local files. A simple example below uses two of each and would fail for me:

```
import xarray as xr
stations = ["pxsc1","obxc1"]
for station in stations:
    for year in ["2019","2020"]: 
        print(f"Working on station: {station} year: {year}")
        ndbc_url  = f"http://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/data/stdmet/{station}/{station}h{year}.nc"
        print(ndbc_url)
        fileout = "noaa_stdmet_{}_{}.nc".format(station,year)
        print(fileout)
        with xr.open_dataset(ndbc_url, engine='netcdf4') as remote:
            remote.to_netcdf(fileout,format="NETCDF4_CLASSIC")
```

The first example seems to go OK, then I get HDF Errors as shown below. The value of `HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING` does not seem to influence the behavior ... I don't really understand that limitation but I've tried it. Are there other ways to make it work?

```
Working on station: pxsc1 year: 2019
http://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/data/stdmet/pxsc1/pxsc1h2019.nc
noaa_stdmet_pxsc1_2019.nc
Working on station: pxsc1 year: 2020
http://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/data/stdmet/pxsc1/pxsc1h2020.nc
noaa_stdmet_pxsc1_2020.nc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\atmospheric\noaa\ndbc_xarray2.py", line 57, in <module>
    ndbc_opendap()
  File "F:\atmospheric\noaa\ndbc_xarray2.py", line 54, in ndbc_opendap
    remote.to_netcdf(fileout,format="NETCDF4")
  File "C:\Users\eli\miniconda3\envs\schimpy_env\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\common.py", line 1499, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\eli\miniconda3\envs\schimpy_env\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\common.py", line 1294, in close
    self._close()
  File "C:\Users\eli\miniconda3\envs\schimpy_env\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\netCDF4_.py", line 512, in close
    self._manager.close(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\eli\miniconda3\envs\schimpy_env\lib\site-packages\xarray\backends\file_manager.py", line 222, in close
    file.close()
  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 2276, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.close
  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 2260, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset._close
  File "netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx", line 1754, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error
```

Comment: This works with `engine='pydap'`. I'll see if someone else has anything to add before I declare that the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be a problem of your code, since everything is working fine on my computer:

```
Working on station: pxsc1 year: 2019
http://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/data/stdmet/pxsc1/pxsc1h2019.nc
noaa_stdmet_pxsc1_2019.nc
Working on station: pxsc1 year: 2020
http://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/data/stdmet/pxsc1/pxsc1h2020.nc
noaa_stdmet_pxsc1_2020.nc
Working on station: obxc1 year: 2019
http://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/data/stdmet/obxc1/obxc1h2019.nc
noaa_stdmet_obxc1_2019.nc
Working on station: obxc1 year: 2020
http://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/data/stdmet/obxc1/obxc1h2020.nc
noaa_stdmet_obxc1_2020.nc
```

However, I think it is because of limited computational power. I assume that Python still has stored the first array (which worked perfectly fine) but does not have enough memory to store the second one. This is why it returns `RuntimeError` and probably restarts the kernel (?).

Try to add `remote.close()` at the end of your with statement. This might solve it.

Is it necessary to use `NETCDF4_CLASSIC`? I prefer to use `NETCDF4` instead, which is more common from what I know (?). I doubt that this would solve your issue, but you could give it a try.

In the following a slightly adapted version of your code:

```
import xarray as xr 

stations = ['pxsc1', 'obxc1']
year = [str(x) for x in range(2019,2020+1,1)]

url_base = 'http://dods.ndbc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/data/stdmet/'
files_in = [f"{url_base}{s}/{s}h{y}.nc" for s in stations for y in year]
files_out = [f"noaa_stdmet_{s}_{y}.nc" for s in stations for y in year]

def load(file, fileout):
    print(f"open file: {file}")
    with xr.open_dataset(file, engine='netcdf4') as remote:
        print(f"writing file: {fileout}")
        remote.to_netcdf(fileout, format="NETCDF4")
        remote.close()

for fin, fout in list(zip(files_in, files_out)):
    load(fin,fout)
```

Comment: For me NETCDF vs NETCDF_CLASSIC does not matter too much. I use _CLASSIC because some API I use wanted the guarantee of no groups.

Comment: One other comment is that I don't believe that close() would be a best practice inside a `with` statement. Resources are automatically closed even if the exit isn't graceful, but maybe there are exceptions with an incomplete or bad implementations. However I thank you for trying it because clearly whatever is off (bad moment with the library or something about my network) doesn't generalize.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I managed to solve it by changing the format to 'NETCDF3_64BIT', which is used to work with files larger than 2 GB for specific versions of NETCDF. It may be something related to memory or the NETCDF version itself. I had this problem only on ubuntu, on windows (on the same machine) the routine ran normally.

Ex:
remote.to_netcdf(fileout,format="NETCDF3_64BIT")

Comment: Thanks. NetCDF3 is a very different format, not implemented in hdf5 and probably not usable with parallel file systems. It might work for some applications but the pdap solution would yield the capabilities I wanted to have in the final file.